# jQuery get element's attribute 'loop'

Tags: jquery

I try to get an attribute of a div element using jQUery 1.6.2

html

```
<div id="scroller" loop="2"></div>
```

js

```
$('#scroller').attr('loop')
```

The above js would always return undefined.

I try to upgrade jquery to 1.6.4, then the same js returns me the word 'loop'. Is this loop attribute a reserved attribute?

I do this becoz of using a library for scrolling text.http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's really going on is `jQuery`'s implementation of `attr`. [`loop` is a boolean attribute for media (`<audio>` and `<video>`) elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/media-elements.html#attr-media-loop), so its presence indicates that the audio or video should loop.

When boolean attributes are used, it is invalid to specify a value other than the attribute name itself. When jQuery checks a boolean attribute, it returns the name of the attribute itself. In this case `[loop]`'s value is its name: `"loop"`.

---

You shouldn't be adding custom attributes to elements unless you're using the `[data-]` attributes specified in HTML5:

```
<div id="scroller" data-loop="2"></div>
```

jQuery supports accessing these `[data-]` attributes with the `data` function:

```
$('#scroller').data('loop'); //returns "2"
```

Comment: This is exactly right. I would also be curious about the role of the "loop" variable. Surely if it's for tracking the number of loops, this is something that can be stored in a JS variable rather than in a DOM node? I don't see any "loop" in Remy's markup.

Comment: @xdazz, then my second point still stands. You shouldn't make up your own attributes unless you're using `[data-]` attributes.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yep, you are right, but I would like to know the reason and why `loop` is special?

Comment: Despite the age of this post - it may be useful to others to know that while the answer from @zzzzBov above is correct, you can also get the bool value for loop in jQuery using the `.prop` method. e.g. `$el.prop('loop')`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, "loop" is some predefined value into jQuery. So, it is a jQuery bug.

Use simple JS for this:

```
document.getElementById("scroller").getAttribute("loop")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug.

`document.getElementById("scroller").getAttribute("loop")` will return 2.