# Replace one attribute with another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

Using jQuery and given this

```
<ul>
<li>
<a external="http://stackoverflow.com" href="home.htm">Link 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="about.htm">Link 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a external="http://google.com" href="contact.html">Link 3</a>
</li>
</ul
```

I want to grab the links with a attribute of "external". Use the value of the external attribute to update the href.

So link 1 and 3 should end up pointing to stackoverflow.com and google.com respectively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get element's attribute 'loop'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925011/jquery-get-elements-attribute-loop)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('a[external]').each(function(i, el){
  $(el).attr('href', $(el).attr('external'));
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed. Will accept your answer after 9 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in `$(document).ready` body:

```
$('li a[external]').each(function() {
   var ext = $(this).attr('external');
   $(this).attr('href', ext);
});
```